# How insects got hits on the wind shield of a car?

Tags: forces, relative-motion

There are rare chances when any insects got hit the wind shield of a car while driving in highway but it makes to wonder that how is that happen ?

Does insect suffered a greater change in momentum as compared to change in momentum of the car or the motor car was moving with larger velocity so it exerted larger force on insect or is there anything else?

Its really confusing like what's the main reason behind this ?

Comment: Are you asking how the car manages to hit the bug, while the air rushes around the car? Or perhaps why the bug is squished while the windshield remains intact? Or why the car doesn't seem to slow when a bug hits the windshield?

Comment: yeah that first one quite make sense as no insect would love to get killed so i guess its an accident so that's my question that why he got hit on windshield? ? change in velocity or momentum or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Conservation of momentum**:

$$\sum p_{before}=\sum p_{after}\implies\\
p_{car,before}+p_{bug,before}=p_{car,after}+p_{bug,after}\implies\\
m_{car}v_{car,before}+m_{bug}v_{bug,before}=m_{car}v_{car,after}+m_{bug}v_{bug,after}
$$

Assume the bug was still in the air before the hit, $v_{bug,before}=0$. After the hit, bug follows car $v_{car,after}=v_{bug,after}=v_{after}$.

$$...\implies\\
m_{car}v_{car,before}=(m_{car}+m_{bug})v_{after}\implies\\
\frac{m_{car}}{m_{car}+m_{bug}}v_{car,before}=v_{after}
$$

All this is just showing that since the bug's mass is so much smaller than the car's $m_{car}\gg m_{bug}$, the final velocity of the car is almost not changed at all, $v_{car,before} \approx v_{after}$.

**Momentum change:**

The bug accelerates to the car's speed in a *very* short time interval. This is an *enormous* momentum change seen from the bug,

$$\Delta p_{bug}=p_{bug,after}-p_{bug,before}=p_{bug,after}=m_{bug}v_{after}$$

since $v_{bug,before}=0\ll v_{bug,after}$.

The momentum change of the car is very small and almost none seen from the car's perspective,

$$\Delta p_{car}=p_{car,after}-p_{car,before}=m_{car}v_{after}-m_{car}v_{before}\approx 0$$

since $v_{car,before} \approx v_{after}$. But this is only an approximation since the difference is negligible at this size-scale. In fact the momentum changes of the bug and car are exactly *equal* (but opposite):

$$\sum p_{before}=\sum p_{after}\implies\\
p_{car,before}+p_{bug,before}=p_{car,after}+p_{bug,after}\implies\\
p_{car,after}-p_{car,before}=p_{bug,before}-p_{bug,after}\implies\\
\Delta p_{car}=-\Delta p_{bug}
$$

So, **yes**, they *do both* experience the same momentum change!

**Newton's 2nd law of motion:**

$$\sum F=\frac{dp_{bug}}{dt}=\frac{\Delta p_{bug}}{\Delta t}$$

Since the collision time duration is *very* small while the momentum change of the bug is *very* big, the force is *very very* large on the bug. The poor bug's body simply cannot withstand that force and splats.

Of course, the exact same force is exerted on the *car* from Newton's 3rd law. But as the car is much stronger and more massive this has extremely little effect. In the end it all comes down to the fragility and small mass of the bug - if it was a steel ball or a stone of the same size but much higher mass, the windshield migth be shattered.

---

In much simpler and more intuitive words think of this:

The bug is accelerated to the speed of the car; acceleration requires force, and so a large force seen from the bug's perspective is applied on the bug to cause this acceleration.

That same force applied on a car of much, much larger mass gives almost no deceleration $F=ma$.

Answer (score 1):

Both the force and the momentum change are equal on the bug and car.

The reason the bug moves along with the car at near the car's original velocity is that the car is 10K to 1000K times as massive as the bug. The final velocity of both objects in an inelastic collision is the weighted average of their velocities and with such a large mass discrepancy the final velocity will be very very close to that of the car.

The reason the bug splats while the windshield is fine, is that the windshield is much stronger than the bug, and the force is simply not enough to damage the glass.